# Stop ZSH from trying to correct ssh to .ssh as an argument

Tags: zsh, autocorrection

This isn't exactly a duplicate, as I want correct_all still active. I do mess up arguments from time to time and ZSH is happy to help me. The rub happens when I am in my home directory and I want to manage sshd with something like `systemctl reload ssh` or `service ssh start` it always asks me if I want to correct to `.ssh`. I usually perform my work in `$HOME` so this gets rather annoying. I have already tried `alias ssh='nocorrect ssh'` and `alias ssh='nocorrectall ssh'` (which I don't think does anything). Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: do you need correction on `systemctl`? if not try instead `alias systemctl='nocorrect systemctl'`; the `ssh` command is unrelated here

Comment: No, `systemctl` is not the problem in my i have `setopt CORRECTALL` set in my `.zshrc`, so no matter where ssh is in my command if I am in my home directory (where .ssh lives) it askes me if that is what I mean. Even `touch ssh` just asked me: `zsh: correct 'ssh' to '.ssh' [nyae]?`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set `CORRECT_IGNORE_FILE`. For example to ignore corrections on all dot files:

```
$ cd
$ PS1='%% ' zsh -f
% setopt CORRECT_ALL
% touch ssh
zsh: correct 'ssh' to '.ssh' [nyae]? a
% CORRECT_IGNORE_FILE='.*'
% touch ssh
% rm ssh
```

This is documented in `zshall(1)`

```
   CORRECT_IGNORE_FILE
          If set, is treated as a pattern during  spelling  correction  of
          file  names.   Any  file  name that matches the pattern is never
          offered as a correction.  For example, if the value is `.*' then
          dot  file  names  will never be offered as spelling corrections.
          This is useful with the CORRECT_ALL option.
```

this requires a somewhat recent version of `zsh` (one more recent than ships with Centos 7). If you're stuck on an old version of `zsh` you'll need to either disable `CORRECT_ALL` or use `nocorrect` to turn the corrections off for each problematical command (which is probably why `CORRECT_IGNORE_FILE` was added).

Comment: Thank you. I missed `zshall` I've read the manpage for `zsh` and the user guide, but it looks like I have a ton more reading to do!

Comment: @user52470 `zshall` contains the whole manual in a single file. The manual is also available as separate pages. `zsh` is merely the front matter. The OVERVIEW section at the top lists the available pages. `zshall` is huge but has the advantage that you can easily search through the whole thing.